# Did the App Engine Custom domain configuration change?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I run several App Engine apps with custom domains, but as of last month (or earlier), the settings do not seem to appear on either the old or new settings page. They are Java apps, not that that should make a difference.

[image: new settings page]

[image: old setting page]

The app is 100% definitely on a custom domain, but for some reason there is no configuration showing up. Should it? How would I edit or remove the custom domain?

Comment: Did you by chance use the new domains interface to set it up? http://domains.google.com/

Comment: It was set up at least 12, maybe 18 months ago - I actually cannot remember how I set it up, I have a vague recollection that at the time it was still tied to the Google Apps interface.

Comment: Ah. It was worth checking. I have a couple of apps, where, like yours, nothing shows up at all inside of the GAE or new Cloud Console. But the domains live on domains.google.com and I'm able to easily point them at different GAE apps from there. Thought there was a chance the same thing happened with you.

Comment: Hmm that's probably what has happened, but for me domains.google.com is invite only - maybe once I am allowed to access it, my domains will magically be there! *fingers crossed* (any Googlers lurking here that can make it so?)

Comment: I need your email address. ;)

Comment: I have to take off for the day, but I found your e-mail address on your website. You should have access now. edit: I see you're in NZ, I think it's limited right now. But I tried to bring you in regardless. Take care!

Comment: Oh, bummer: "We’re sorry. Google Domains may not be available in your country" - not sure if that's why no domains are showing up there. Appreciate your efforts all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom domain mapping will not show up on the [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com) if it was set up using the older functionality within the Google Apps [Administration Console](http://admin.google.com). If this is the case, you should see the configuration within the [Google Apps Admin Console](http://admin.google.com) for the domain, signing in with the Domain administrator account and navigate to the "App Engine apps" section (most likely under "More controls").

Comment: This has answered the question, it seems the legacy apps have no info in settings, but logging in to the old google apps account reveals the 'app engine apps' settings and likewise newer ones do appear in the new domain console (if you are logged in with the google account that originally set it up)